# HTML Resize font to fit screen resolution

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am very new in web development and I am trying to display some information using the table tags in such way that the content of that table always fit a screen height.

The page would have the following structure:

o - 1 big table

o --> The first row would have 1 row ( which is a table of 2 rows)

o --> The second row would be divided in 3 parts, 3 different tables representing different information.

```
+------------------------------------------+
|     First row of table                   |
+-------+-----------------------+----------|
| Inner |     Inner table       |Inner     |
| table |         2             |table 3   |
|   1   |                       |          |
+------------------------------------------+
```

And the issue that I am facing is to manage to adjust automatically the font of the text being displayed to reduce automatically until there is no scroll bar - Some kind of automatic un-zoom.

After some googling, I understood I should dig into JQuery to get somehow the size of the screen and resize automatically all the font of all my object to finally match this size. But since I am very new in this technology I am kind of lost...

Here is html I am using with dummy text :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-condensed nopadding  table-striped">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th class="col-md-2 nopadding text-center">First Name</th>
               <th class="col-md-2 nopadding text-center">Last name</th>
               <th class="col-md-2 nopadding text-center">Office id</th>
               <th class="col-md-2 nopadding text-center">Other info</th>
               <th class="col-md-2 nopadding text-center">Other info</th>
               <th class="col-md-2 nopadding text-center">Other info</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <p align="center"><b>My Name</b></p>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <p align="center"><b>Last name</b></p>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <p align="center"><b>Office id </b></p>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <p align="center"><b>Bla bla bla </b></p>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <p align="center"><b>Bla bla bla</b></p>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <p align="center"><b>Bla bla bla</b></p>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-condensed nopadding ">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th class="col-md-1 nopadding" style="width:15%"></th>
               <th class="col-md-10 nopadding" style="width:70%"></th>
               <th class="col-md-1 nopadding" style="width:15%"></th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td style="width: 15%">
                  <table border="1" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <th>Incoming events</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>Meeting 1</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>Meeting 2 </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>Meeting 3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td>Meeting 4</td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </td>
               <td style="width: 70%">
                  <table border="1" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
                     <thead>
                        <tr>
                           <th style="vertical-align:top ; color:orange">Must do</th>
                           <th style="vertical-align:top; color:green">Should do</th>
                        </tr>
                     </thead>
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review Internal presentation </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review external presentation </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                           <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                           <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                           <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                           <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                           <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                           <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                           <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                           <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                           <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                           <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                           <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                           <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                           <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                           <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                           <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                           <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                           <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                           <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                           <td> Review bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </td>
               <td style="width: 15%">
                  <table border="1" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed" style=" table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word;">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <th>Achieved</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Achieved bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Achieved bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td> Achieved bla bla </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td align="center">. . .</td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <meta content="60;URL=/" http-equiv="refresh"/>
      <p align="center"><b>Some useless text</b><br/></p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Use [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to define different font sizes on different screens. In some cases, responsive font sizes can solve your problem.

> 1vw = 1% of viewport width
>
> 1vh = 1% of viewport height
>
> 1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller
>
> 1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger

Comment: How can I dynamically use this media queries so depending on the number of rows I have it fits my screen ? after browsing the web I cannot use inline css which prevent me from the backend side to give some specific percentage. Or do I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wrap in your css (but there are other solutions that you can use too), for example..

css:

```
#wrapper
{
    width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

html/or whatever file:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper"> <!-- main div for the body that wraps -->
        <!-- put your codes and whatever inside the wrapper div -->
    </div>
</body>
```